# Duda con mi primer array de Python

Tags: python, array

estoy aprendiendo Python con Unipython y como primer array me sale un ejemplo con algo que no entiendo.

El ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
b = ['2.36', 'elefante', 1010, 'rojo']
print (b)
l4 = b[0:3:2]
print(l4)
```

La duda que tengo es que al ejecutar `l4` se imprime como ['2.36', 1010]. Pero siendo [0:3:2] ¿no debería imprimirse ['2.36', 'rojo', 1010]?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintaxis `b[0:3:2]` es un *slice* (rodaja) con tres argumentos:

- El primero (`0`) es el índice de inicio
- El segundo (`3`) es el índice final (no incluído en el resultado)
- El tercero (`2`) es el "paso", o sea, el incremento entre sucesivos subíndices.

Así pues se leería como "desde el índice 0 (inclusive) hasta el 3 (no inclusive) en saltos de 2 en 2".

Por tanto tomará los índices 0 y 2, (y 4 que sería el próximo ya no entra porque es mayor de 3).

De ahí el resultado `['2.36', 1010]` que observas

### Bonus

Aprovecho para contarte que cualquiera de los tres argumentos es opcional.

- Si omites el "paso" por defecto usará 1. Ej: `b[0:3]` selecciona los índices 0, 1, y 2.
- Si omites el inicio, por defecto usará "desde el inicio del iterable". Ej: `b[:3]` selecciona también los índices 0, 1, y 2
- Si omites el final por defecto usará "hasta el final del iterable (inclusive el último)". Así `b[3:]` seleccionaría los índices 3, y 4 (pues este iterable tiene 4 elementos).

Puedes omitir inicio y fin: `b[:]` te devolverá la lista completa. Puede parecer inútil pero es un truco frecuente para obtener una copia de la lista, en lugar de tener que poner `b.copy()`

Otro truco que puedes encontrar por ahí es: `b[::-1]` en el que se omite principio y final, pero se utiliza paso -1. En este caso selecciones los índices del último al primero, por orden inverso. Es una forma de obtener la lista "al revés".

Comment: Muchas gracias, la respuesta es mucho mejor de lo que buscaba

Comment: si, estoy esperando los minutos que pide para aceptarla :)